# Why is לְשַׁבֵּחַ pronounced leshabe'ah and not leshabacha?

Tags: hebrew, chanuka, song-poetry, pronunciation

This is the last word of the first line of Ma'oz Tzur.
I've always sung leshabe'ah but wouldn't this require a yud between the Bet and Chet?

Comment: aaron, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I recommend taking a look at our [Beginner's Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/2) to Mi Yodeya.